# divs positioned vertically instead of horizontally php css3

Tags: css

my platform divs (several squares according to rows in database) with 3 children-divs inside are positioned vertically inside the wrapper div instead of horizontally. I set the '-webkit-box-orient' to horizontal for the platform div as well as for its 3 children but I don't get it to work. Thank you for your tip! Hobby

```
<div id="wrapper">


<?php
$platforms = get_platforms();

foreach ($platforms as $platform)
{
echo 
'<div class="platform">
    <div class="platform_left"></div>
        <div class="platform_middle"></div>
        <div class="platform_right"></div>
    </div>';
}
?>

</div>

//And here is the css:


#wrapper{
max-width: 960px;
margin: 180px 0px;
border: 1px solid black;
background:-webkit-radial-gradient(top,#99CCFF,#E6F0FF);
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
background:-moz-radial-gradient(top,#99CCFF,#E6F0FF);
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
}

.platform{
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
width: 435px;
height: 180px;
background: #99CCFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110, 110, 100, .7) 8px 8px 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(110, 110, 100, .7) 8px 8px 8px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divs inside od div.platform have same width as their parent (div.platform)

you have to set them `width: 33%` (or less in case you want to use borders,margins and paddings) and then set `float` property to **left**.

there is not need of editing PHP part

W3c says:

> The box-orient property is not supported in any of the major browsers.

*sorry for my english*

Comment: thanks Mire, if I set the float: left they all disappear. I need min. 45% per .class_platform so all platform_children fit but that should still fit 2 platforms in 1 row next to each other.

Comment: @Hobby99, hope I understand you... you want to fit 3 divs positioned horizontally into one div. this means you have to set width of each child to max. 33%. Why? because parent *div.platform* has width 100%, so 100/3 is 33.3 => 33%. It is impossible to fit 3*45% into 100%. If you need min. 45% now, you have to set bigger value to width property on *div.platform* element but width of children have to be max. 33%. sorry for my english

Comment: Mire, thanks! I want 2 platforms in 1 row. 2x45%=90%+margin&padding of total 10% =100%. My problem is that even though 2 platforms would actually fit next to each other under these settings, they dont. They are vertical instead. And if I use the float:left;-property all platforms are gone.

Comment: @Hobby99, do you have some live preview?

Comment: Hey Mire, now I understood!! Im a newby, took a bit longer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If your math is correct, there must be something else interfering.  Are you using a CMS or anything else that might have some underlying CSS?  Sometimes I find it helpful to not just inspect an element but to hover my mouse over an element with the element inspector turned on (if you don't know what I'm talking about, make sure you have something like Firebug in Firefox, or right click on element to inspect it in Chrome) -- this will show you the element's true dimensions.  Also look at the "computed style."

If you see a width you don't expect, go further up the page and inspect each element until you find the one with an unexpected width.

I have this problem frequently when designing site themes with an underlying framework.  If the math inside your wrapper is correct, something is squeezing the wrapper div's dimensions.  Also look for gutters - unexpected padding or margins coming from another style sheet.